# How do i pass variable from app.js to index.html?

Tags: html-framework-7

I am a beginner for webpack and EMCA script, although i do not consider i am new JS developer let say i use JS here and there but not my main development langauge, and I got confused by all the imports of js and how it can be applied to my framework7 apps.

Sorry for some simple questions below,

i have my src/js/app.js

> ```
> import $$ from 'dom7';
> import Framework7 from 'framework7/framework7.esm.bundle.js';
>
> // Import F7 Styles
> import 'framework7/css/framework7.bundle.css';
>
> // Import Icons and App Custom Styles
> import '../css/icons.css';
> import '../css/app.less';
>
> // Import own application auth class
> import 'app-auth/lib/index.js';
>
> // Import Routes
> import routes from './routes.js';
>
> // Import main app component
> import App from '../app.f7.html';
>
> // trying to initialize the Auth class 
> // not sure whether should be using "const" or "var"
> var auth = new Auth();
>
> var app = new Framework7({
>   root: '#app', // App root element
>   component: App, // App main component
>
>   name: 'mos_app', // App name
>   theme: 'auto', // Automatic theme detection
>
>
>   // App routes
>   routes: routes,
>
>   // ** i have tried below, but not sure is correct ? 
>   auth: auth,
> });
> ```

so from the above app.js, not sure how it is passed to the 
index.html or the rest of my pages_x.html ?

> ```
> <!-- built styles file will be auto injected -->
> </head>
> <body>
>   <script>
>     // Method login
>     // parameters username, password, database
>     console.log(app.name);
>     app.auth.login('admin', 'admin', 'mydbname').then(console.log);
>
>     // Method logout
>     app.auth.logout().then(console.log);
>   </script>  
>   <div id="app"></div>
>
>   <!-- built script files will be auto injected -->
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

when I checked my console, errors saying that variable is not
defined, I not sure where to begin and what to google search for, but some how is my insufficient knowledge of the JS ECMA. Do appreciate if any of you can
provide me some advice on how to get that to work?

I basically need to load my own node_modules and then initialize it and use it, which
the node_module is a class.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers load things somewhat predictably pretty much in the order they appear in the final html. So the script tag in the head is executed way before the injected script at the bottom of the body.

When you call the app constructor 'var app = new Framework7({...})' , it only parses the options it knows about, you can't define variables there. The property "auth" is silently skipped.

My opinion here is that you should avoid splitting the code, and execute whatever you need in src/js/app.js.

If you want to execute something after loading the framework, you should pass an 'on' object to the app constructor with an 'init' function

something like this:

```
var app = new Framework7({
  root: '#app', // App root element
  component: App, // App main component

  name: 'mos_app', // App name
  theme: 'auto', // Automatic theme detection

  // App routes
  routes: routes,

  // HERE:
  on: {
    init: function(){
      //do something
    }
  }
});
```

You can check this out here https://framework7.io/docs/app.html

However, logins are usually somehting to do after some input so you might want to take a look at handling events.